# How to rebuild newly replace Hard drive in IBM x3650 M3 raid 10 to recover the linux OS

Tags: linux, ibm

This is my first encounter with a defective server so I hope you could help me. 
The server is not booting anymore with only blinking cursor on the screen. I have an IBM x3650 M3 with 8 300GB disks. First, one HD in slot 1 is amber light(failed). Everything is still OK since the server is configured raid10. While waiting for the replacement disk another HD failed this time in slot 0 causing the server unbootable. Can I still recover the OS? I am ready to replace the two disks. Would you able to advice me the correct procedures. I have already browse the webbios(Ctrl-H) and found slot0 and 1 has unconfigured bad status. I tried to insert the new disk in slot0 leaving the other defective in slot1.In the configuration wizard there's the way to add in a group and span  ans somehow bring the disk to online status but I just cancelled the wizard cause Im not sure yet if this is the right way.

Comment: You have 8 HD drives configured as Raid10 (no spare or unconfigured disks). So, you should survive 4 disk failures given that they belong to the same mirroring set.

Comment: You've said that you have eight disks, but posted no information on how they are arranged logically. What are the actual arrays in this system? We can't assume that they are all a part of the same RAID10.

Comment: In physical view slot0 and 1 shows unconfigured bad.  Slot 2 to 7 is online

Comment: @Khaled I didn't see any hot spare drive set. In physical view slot0 and 1 shows unconfigured bad.  Slot 2 to 7 is online.@SmallLoanOf1M  In logical view Span Drive Group:0, Raid10 <br/>  Virtual drive:1, 835.394 GB optimal <br/>  Drives, Span:0    Slot:2, online    Slot:3,online <br/>  Drives, Span1    Slot:4, online    Slot:5,online <br/>  Drives, Span2    Slot6:, online    Slot7:, online <br/>